# Protecting values of an ajax form of inspect element, how to protect?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How can I protect my ajax form of inspect element?
I'm creating a system and I forgot  that the user can edit the value of a hidden input using inspect element.

Please look this code:

```
<input type="hidden" class="id" value="<?=$array["id"]?>" />
```

And the ajax:

```
 var id = $(this).parent().find('.id').val();
```

If the id is **5** and I edit to **2** the ajax will get **2**

Can anyone help me?

Comment: thats the start of becoming a hacker. well done

Comment: You could "**uglify**" your code using various tools like UglifyJS, but that's about it. Nothing much you could do about it. The only thing you **could** do is put server side validations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply can't. You can never assume the data send from the client is trustworthy. That's why you should ALWAYS check input on the server. Checking it on the client is just an extra measure to improve efficiency. It's NEVER an alternative and should never be the ONLY security measure.

But, as an additional security. You could add a second field, which contains a hashed value of the hidden field (salted of course, otherwise it is pointless). Then check on the server if the value still matches up with the hash (by doing the hashing with the same salt value again).

But you shouldn't trust that too much either.

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" class="id" value="<?=$array["id"];?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="hash" class="id" value="<?=md5($array["id"] . "somerandomstring");?>" />
```

Then on the server check if it still matches up and it hasn't been tampered with.

```
$id = $_GET["id"];
$hash = $_GET["hash"]
if(md5($id . "somerandomstring") == $hash) {
    // it's okay
} else { 
    // he changed it 
}
```

When you receive the id and the hash value from the client over AJAX, just check if hashing the id again with the same salt value gives the same hash. If not, it means he changed the id.

But you should still check if the user is allowed to work on the item with this id. And probably you should use sha instead of md5, because md5 is highly insecure.

The salt must be secret and the same on both places. A "salt" value is a random piece of code which is added to the value you want to hash, so hackers have a harder time trying to bruteforce your original value based on the hash (but not impossible).

Add a timeout of a few minutes and it might be safe enough.

Comment: I'm studying programming so i did this method. can you tell me how can i send a few to my ajax code? I could use session but i'm using this html code in a while (php).

Comment: I edited my answer with a way you could still verify it client side. But I would still recommend checking server side if the user has the required authority.

Comment: I saw your code, thx, I had this idea too, but how can I check in the server side (php)?  (Edit): i think I understood now, I need to check this hash and the id in the php script, right?

Comment: The second part IS the server side. When you receive the id and the hash value from the client over AJAX, just check if hashing the id again with the salt value gives the same hash. If not, it means he changed the id.

Comment: Yes, I'll do now, I think it's safe to use on my website. Thank you so much.